# How to query Lucene to retrieve only documents with field values in given ranges?

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to perform basic Lucene query with sql-like characteristics: retrieve only documents which have numeric field values in specific ranges.

Like "text:hello world AND numeric_x:between 50 and 100 AND numeric_Y: between 100 and 200".

Thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirement - including 100 and 200:

```
numeric_Y:[100 TO 200]
```

excluding 100 and 200 (between 100 and 200):

```
numeric_Y:{100 TO 200}
```

.. or a combination, including 101 and 200:

```
numeric_Y:{100 TO 200]
```